# UltraVNC -- connect without disrupting current user

Tags: remote-access, ultravnc

Using UltraVNC, can I connect without disrupting the current user?

Comment: This depends on how you have the server configured, and what platform the server is running on..... and if the user is at their desk :)

Comment: Yeah, what exactly is disrupting?

Comment: disrupting = User A is currently physically operating on the server. User B wants to connect from a client, without logging off User A.

Answer (score 0):

TightVNC is similar to UltraVNC...You can connect without disrupting the current user, but you have to configure some options, server side (like not requiring the current user to approve your remote connection).

The biggest trick is to keep **your mouse outside of the VNC window**, so that their mouse is not controlled by yours...

Comment: That's called spying >;)

Comment: @John: he asked how to do it without disturbing...I assumed that's what he meant :)

Comment: I'm only playin with you. Lol